# Data not get loaded into table in Scala

Tags: scala, azure, apache-spark, azure-storage, apache-spark-sql

I use below code snippet to load data in to table. but data is not get loaded in to table.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Calendar
import sqlContext.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType, FloatType, DoubleType}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.rand
import scala.io.Source

val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

val TextFiledata= sc.textFile("wasb://Test.txt")

val schema = StructType(
    Array(
      StructField("ABC", StringType, true),
      StructField("XYZ", StringType, true)
    )
)

val mapped = TextFiledata
  .map(_.split("#|#"))
  .filter(r => r(0) != "ABC")
  .map(p => Row(p(0), p(1))


val DF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(mapped ,schema)
DF.registerTempTable("Table")
```

Comment: In the code you have posted, you are not performing any actions, so how do you know that data isn't loaded? Spark does lazy evaluation so it won't actually do anything before you call an action...

Comment: val sqlStatement = """
   select distinct(ABC) from DF 
"""
val sqlResultsDF = sqlContext.sql(sqlStatement)

sqlResultsDF.show()

This is the action I am performing on the DF.Its running long time not returning any value.

Comment: You have to provide us with proper functional code. I understand you may want to give a toy example, but your problem is almost guaranteed to be due to some syntactical error, so if you want help you have to provide us with the right code and a snippet of your input data. What you have provided here is not functional - you have for example registered `DF` as "Table" but your query reads `select .. from DF`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code `val TextFiledata= sc.textFile("wasb://Test.txt")`, I think the file path for HDFS based on Azure Blob storage is not correct.

WASB URI syntax is:

> `wasb[s]://<containername>@<accountname>.blob.core.windows.net/<path>`

So you should refer to the file as `wasbs:///Test.txt` or `wasbs://<ContainerName>@<StorageAccountName>.blob.core.windows.net/Test.txt`.

When using the `wasb://` URI scheme, Spark accesses the data from Azure Storage Blobs endpoint using unencrypted HTTP. We can use `wasbs://` to make sure that the data is accessed via HTTPS.